# SQL Error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a `varchar` column to `date` or `datetime` but I don't understand why it's not possible it should work and I don't see any kind of error.

The column values is `31-07-2017` and the type is `Varchar(250)`. I tried `convert` and `cast` and I get the same error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Does anyone have any idea on why it's like this?

Comment: please show us your query

Comment: The moral of the story here is to not store dates as text.

Comment: try this: "SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-25');" or you can learn more from here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: Your date is ambiguous. If you must store a date as something that's not a date, use ISO '20170731'

Comment: No it's to update vakue to date so i can use it, also i know very well how to convert  or cast  i otught mmaybe some one seen this error it's not logical i dontt see any error in the query or values

Comment: below more info 
Column to convert : Account_date_creation ==> Varchar(250) 
Target convert convertion : Date 
Values lenth : 10 
values structure : DD/MM/YEAR
SELECT [ID_DimAccounts]
      ,[Account_ID]
      ,[Account_N]
      ,[Account_Pseudo]
      ,[Account_Name]
      ,[Account_surname]
      ,[Date_of_birth]
      ,[Account_Mobile]
      ,[Accountè_Status]
      ,[POS_ID]
      ,[Account_Email]
      ,CONVERT(date,[Account_date_creation],105)
  FROM [LudWin-Datawarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Account]
instead of convert i used  CAST( Account_date_creatin as date )

Comment: Can I see your query ?

Comment: @AtrinNoori the query was correct the issue was one records in date was really a text  thus that's why i had the error it's very strrange how the text was there in firsst place also i check by lenth to see if all the values had the same lenth but it only gives the max lenth for all values any way thank you and it as a very very very  amateur mistake

Comment: @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR Thats Ok, Happy You Found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, it's a very very stupid mistake, there was one column with a text format I couldn't see it because I checked with length, but the SQL gives max length so I used group by and manually check dates until I found one column that's not correct in 1 m account records

Answer (score 6):

The conversion error is because your session setting is other than `DATEFORMAT dmy` or `varchar` values do not conform to `DMY` format.

For the latter case, run the query below to identify problem values:

```
SELECT YourDateColumn AS InvalidDate 
FROM dbo.YourTable 
WHERE
    YourDateColumn IS NOT NULL
    AND TRY_CONVERT(date, YourDateColumn, 103) IS NULL;
```

As @TimBiegeleisen mentioned in a comment, it is best to choose the most appropriate column type (`date` in this case) for the data to be stored. Not only will this avoid errors like this, it will improve performance and better ensure data integrity.

Comment: Hello, Dan Guzman
I already searched for null or space in the columns but there is none i also need to mentionnne i know all of this i tryed to convert to 103 for FR or 105 for ITalien (-) or even US for 1 but it's still same i also tryed to Cast as date  but it's really something very strange

Comment: If you're still getting errors I'd suggest you have a variety of formats in your column. If so, your data has basically lost all meaning. For example, if you have the value `'01-03-2020'` you now don't know if it's meant to be 01 March or 03 January.

Comment: @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR, did you run the query in my answer?

Comment: yes same error i tryed every trick in the book

Comment: Hi Laurn, already tryed every possible format

Comment: You missed by point, @OUSSAMABEYGAHAR . If you have a variety of formats, then you are going to get errors what ever style you apply when you do it to the whole column. You may well be better off dropping the column and creating a new one with the correct data type. You'll lose the values, but they're meaningless anyway, so they might as well all be `NULL`.

Comment: the point is that i did already clean the data and this one single row passd thru i dont know it slipped